# .htaccess to parent directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying forward /test/12 to test?var=12 using htaccess

I have set up my `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ test?$1 [L]
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't supposed to be `test?somevar=12` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix it!

Comment: What actually happens with your current rules? What is `test?var=12` expected to map to? This itself is not a valid end-point?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ test.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [B,QSA]
```

`[^/]` means "any character that's not a slash". Naturally this means that "text" cannot contain any slashes, but your URL will be matched correctly.

Also note the `[B]` which is one of many options you can add to a rewrite rule. `[B]` means that any `&`s and some other characters will be escaped.

now in your `test.php`

```
print_r($_GET);
```

will output for url `http://localhost/test/123/456/asdf`:

```
Array
(
    [var1] => 123
    [var2] => 456
    [var3] => asdf
)
```

Comment: The rewrite still isn't working, I'm just getting a not found error at `test/12`. I have the engine turned on and AllowOverride All on too. When I make a deliberate error in my .htaccess it crashes the server.

Comment: try adding `Options +MultiViews` above rewrite

Comment: I added it, still nothing. I have other config files in my /etc/apache2/sites-available. Are these likely to be affecting it? I thought the whole point of .htaccess is that you could configure the rules at directory level?

Comment: and your apache2 mod_rewrite is enabled ?

Comment: # sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
It's rewriting my http to https no problem. I disabled that for testing this though so that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: The OP only has 1 variable path segment (that maps to 1 URL parameter), so where did all of `^test/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([^/]*)/(.*)$` come from?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was adding the .htaccess in the wrong directory. I should have added it in the parent directory, but I was adding `^test/(.+)$ test?$1` in the `test` directory.

I wanted to take the full query after the trailing slash in the url, so the rule I used in the parent directory was `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?$1`. This in turn caused a circular loop so I redirected to a directory within the parent so the final working rule that took the final part of the url string after the `/` and forwarded it as a variable to `test.php?$1` looked like this.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/test.php?$1